# React router (v4) - separate public and protected views

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm creating an app with two groups of views:

1. Public views - login, register, reset password etc (not available for logged user, redirect to first protected view if so).
2. Protected views - access after login (not available for not logged user, redirect to login page if so).

This is my code now. Unfortunately it is not working as I want. After login, content of the site is changed, but URL is still `/login`.

`logged` variable is taken from redux store which determines current state of login.

Important thing is wrappers for views - for logged user I want wrap views within `<Content />` and for not logged `<Sign />`. It contains my navigation etc.

```
return (
  <Router>
    <>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to={logged ? appUrls.investmentList : appUrls.login} />} />

      <Route
        render={() => logged ? (
          <Content>
            <Switch>
              <Route path={appUrls.investmentList} component={InvestmentList} />
              <Route path={appUrls.assumptionList} component={AssumptionList} />
            </Switch>
          </Content>
        ) : (
          <Sign>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path={appUrls.login} component={Login} />
              <Route exact path={appUrls.register} component={Register} />
              <Route exact path={appUrls.resetPassword} component={ResetPassword} />
              <Route path={appUrls.setPassword} component={SetPassword} />
            </Switch>
          </Sign>
        )}
      />
    </>
  </Router>
);
```

---

**Updated**

`Login` component

```
import * as React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {bindActionCreators, Dispatch} from "redux";
import {login} from "../../actions/login";
import LoginForm from "../login_form/LoginForm";
import SignHeader from "../sign_header/SignHeader";
import SignSeparator from "../sign_separator/SignSeparator";
import SocialButtons from "../social_buttons/SocialButtons";

interface IDispatchProps {
    login: typeof login;
}

interface IProps extends IDispatchProps {}

const Login: React.SFC<IProps> = props => {

    return (
        <>
            <SignHeader>Zaloguj się za pomocą</SignHeader>
            <SocialButtons />

            <SignSeparator />

            <SignHeader>lub adresem email</SignHeader>
            <LoginForm onSubmit={(data: any) => props.login(data)} />
        </>
    );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
    ...bindActionCreators({login}, dispatch),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Comment: can you show your Login component?, probably you need to use withRouter HOC to apply the bindings for react-router-dom

Comment: @AngelSalazar sure. I've added Login component in question. There's no magic there. Let me know If you want see more code. I'm using TypeScript, but it shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: does the code below work?

Answer (score 0):

This may fix it

```
export default withRouter(
  connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
);
```